# Unchecking all checkboxes with the escape key

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I'm trying to enable the user to uncheck all checkboxes with the escape key.
I found this code snippet that does the job, but by clicking a button.

```
<form> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >one<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >two<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >three<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >four<br> 
  <input type=button name="CheckAll" value="Select_All" onClick="check(true,10)"> 
  <input type=button name="UnCheckAll" value="UnCheck All Boxes" onClick="check(false,10)"> 
</form>
```

```
function check(checked,total_boxes){ 
     for ( i=0 ; i < total_boxes ; i++ ){ 
       if (checked){   
         document.forms[0].checkBox[i].checked=true; 
        }else{  
         document.forms[0].checkBox[i].checked=false; 
        } 
    }   
} 

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
        // uncheck all checkboxes 
    }
});
```

The code doesn't work on checkboxes that are not in a  tag.
Sometimes I use checkboxes for CSS only on-click events, which are not inside of a form.
The use case here is for CSS only menu pop-ups and drop-downs.
I'm trying to make them accessible by allowing the user to close with the escape key.
Sure, it's not CSS only any more, but I need to improve accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
function allCB(checked){
    document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(cb=>cb.checked=checked)
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',_=>event.key === 'Escape' && allCB(false));
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('click',ev=>ev.target.type=="button" && allCB(ev.target.name=="CheckAll"));
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkBox">one</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkBox">two</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkBox">three</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkBox">four</label><br>
  <input type=button name="CheckAll" value="Select_All">
  <input type=button name="UnCheckAll" value="UnCheck All Boxes">
</form>
```